# How to create a CommandButton with a dropdown

Tags: visualforce, commandbutton

Is it possible, and what would be the approach, to create an `apex:commandButton` which displays a dropdown when clicked, in the same fashion as the Manage Members button on the Campaign object:

[image]

I'm comfortable with writing the logic behind the button but it's the actual display I'm not sure how to start. Is there a Salesforce native way of doing this or should I be looking at something javascript/jQuery?

To clarify the dropdown list I would list to be dynamic. I've just been looking at this approach, and it works BUT I need the drop down/apex:commandLinks to be dynamically generated:
http://www.tehnrd.com/custom-multi-select-buttons/

**More detail:**

I want to add a button to a custom product entry screen which will add a group of Products as OpportunityLineItems, however the Products are categorised by year and the choice will be one of the years or all of them (not a mixture of years).

Just found an idea for it:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BqRhAAK

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no Visualforce element that can do this.

You can use [semantic-ui dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html) that looks like have a specification with what you looking for.

Comment: Thanks that looks interesting but I wasn't clear in my question. The drop down ideally needs to be dynamically generated I'm not sure how I would do that with this approach?

Comment: you can create SelectList and SelectOptions dynamically. here the example : http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_selectList.htm